# how to capture USSD response in android

Tags: android, ussd

```
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            String hash = Uri.encode("#"); 
            String ussd = ""+code+hash; 
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ussd));
            callIntent.putExtra("simSlot", 1);
            callIntent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 1);
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

Please help to capture ussd response in variable

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at the moment there no standard way to capture USSD responses in android. And it seems there will be no way in future to do that.